# How can I have two date variables in datetime2 type in sql?

Tags: sql, insert, datetime2

I want to insert these values into existing table.

```
insert Schedule
    ([Title], MeetingTime)
values
    (N'First meeting', ('2018-10-9 18:30:00' and '2018-11-13 18:30:00' )),
    (N'Second meeting', ('2018-11-6 18:00:00' and '2018-12-4 18:00:00' ))
==================================
[Title] NVARCHAR(32) not null
MeetingTime DATETIME2 not null
```

I used `and`, but it is incorrect syntax.
How can I have two or more values in `DATETIME2` type?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 4 separate inserts?

Comment: You can not have multiple values within the same column in the same row. You will need to either modify the table to have a second datetime2 column, or create a new row for each date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert Schedule
([Title], MeetingTime)
values
(N'First meeting', '2018-10-9 18:30:00'),
(N'First meeting', '2018-11-13 18:30:00'),
(N'Second meeting', '2018-11-6 18:00:00'),
(N'Second meeting','2018-12-4 18:00:00' );
```

This is assuming that Title is not the table unique key.